# aspnet_wp.exe can't start

Tags: asp.net

I have a brand new computer installed with .net Framework 4. I have a 80004005 error that says something like "aspnet_wp.net can't be started because you have the wrong credentials" (sorry, the error message is in another language than english).

I tried adding userName="SYSTEM" in the  section of the machine.config but it didn't work.

I'm desperate, I don't know what to try and I'm normally a Linux guy so my experience with Windows can't help.

Comment: are you logged in as an administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, finally, here is what we did. It may not be the cleanest way of doing it but it finally works.

I had framework 1.x, 2.x et 4.x . What we did is that we removed framework 1.x et 4.x with this command in each of the roots of the frameworks :

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -ua
```

After, we may have re-installed 2.x but we did so many thing that I don't remember well.

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Also, make sure that the ASPNET account on the computer is active and unlocked.

I only kept 2.x for the moment but I guess that I could just keep 4.x if I would want to. I'm afraid to try because I don't want to go back to this problem again.

**I must warn you** that this should be the last thing you try when you tried everything else and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

this sometimes resolves issues by reinstalling asp.net

Comment: Ah sorry to hear that, do you have an entry in the windows event log you can post?